# Trigger event on state change, in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, android-jetpack-compose

I have a web view and a TextField. I want to trigger web view reload when textField triggers the onGo action or its value change.

Below is mutable string:

```
var urlValue: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf(DefaultUrl)
```

the textField looks like this

```
var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(DefaultUrl) }

val textStyle = androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle(
    fontSize = ToolbarUrlFontSize.sp
)

BasicTextField(
    value = textFieldValue,
    onValueChange = { text ->
        textFieldValue = text
    },
   
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Go),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onGo = {
            urlValue.value = textFieldValue
        }
    )
) { innerTextField ->
    innerTextField()
}
```

And below is the code for web view:

```
AndroidView({ context ->
    WebView(context).apply {
        if(urlValue.value.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.i("TAG", "MainComposable: ${urlValue.value}")
            loadUrl(urlValue.value)
        }

        webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView,
                url: String
            ): Boolean {
                view.loadUrl(url)
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the web view doesn't reload the new URL. How can I do the new URL load on the go action trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code to render in WebView:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun WebPageScreen(urlToRender: String) {
    AndroidView(factory = {
        WebView(it).apply {
            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?
                ): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }, update = {
        it.loadUrl(urlToRender)
    })
}
```

`AndroidView()` composable function's `update` block is invoked after the layout is inflated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `update` property.
Something like:

```
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            WebView(it).apply {
                this.webViewClient  =  WebViewClient()
                this.loadUrl("defaultUrl")
            }
        },
        update = {
            it.loadUrl(urlValue)
        },
    )
```